# Which Big-Data Frameworks have most simple interfaces?

Tags: bigdata

I found that Apache-Spark has pretty much simple interface and easy to use. But I want to know about other interfaces.

Can anyone give me a ranking of Big-Data frameworks in base of simplicity of their interfaces. also this is useful to express most simple and complex interfaces in base of your experiences.

Definitely this question is about some frameworks with same tasks. For example a selection between Flink and Spark just in your opinion. Detailed comparison is so lengthy and this is not my purpose. Just a selection or ranking on your opinions is sufficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think that it is impossible to answer this question *comprehensively*, at least for the following **reasons**:

- big data frameworks have different **goals** and target different **knowledge domains**, so the comparison simply doesn't make much sense;
- most big data frameworks (and other programming frameworks, for that matter) have *multiple interfaces*, and frequently those **sets of interfaces** are significantly different (the *intersection* is small), so there is a risk of comparing apples and oranges;
- trying to compare anything (in this case, interfaces), using *simplicity* as a criterion, involves a significant amount of **subjectivity** - what one person *perceive* as very simple, another person might find quite complex;
- the **variety** and the **number** of *big data frameworks* is mind-boggling (for example, see https://github.com/onurakpolat/awesome-bigdata); the same applies to a related topic of *machine learning frameworks* (for example, see https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning);
- corollary from the points above: a **comprehensive** comparison (considering all the above-mentioned issues) would go far beyond the **scope** of a single answer on this site, in volume and effort - it would be more like a long research paper, a book chapter or even a book.

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr. I agree with your answer. But I just want to hear opinion of other experts in base of their experiences and their sense with various interfaces. For example you maybe work with various frameworks. I want to know which of them has better interface in your opinion. Definitely this question is about some frameworks with same tasks. For example a selection between Flink and Spark just in your opinion. As your answer detailed comparison is so lengthy and this is not my purpose.

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer. Thanks:)

Comment: @OmidEbrahimi: You're very welcome :-). I very much understand the reasoning behind your question. It's just that this type of questions (opinion-based) are not in favor on StackExchange (and I actually disagree with that, but most of the time try to follow the guidelines). Despite that and surprisingly, opinion-based questions and answers are no such rarity on StackExchange. I guess, it's more of issue of moderators' discretion and personal (subjective) tolerance for a particular question/topic. My main point is that SE is unlikely the best outlet for a _comprehensive_ treatment of the topic.